Does rate vol impacts treasury prices
I was reading about bond convexity and was trying to link it with my understanding of gamma for vanilla options.
My first question is: Where do we pay for convexity when we buy a Treasury Bond? In a vanilla call option we buy convexity through theta. So as time passes we lose money, and that's why we have some convexity. What about for Treasuries?
My intuition would say that there's also something related to time since rates get "realized" as time passes. Is there a theta also for Treasuries?
My second question is related to rates vol. Does high vol increase treasury prices? For example if I take a zero-coupon bond. If rates vol is high does it impact my bond prices and how? I would say in some sense yes since a bond earn more money on the upside than on the downside because of convexity then for a symmetric distribution of rates if vol is high we have more chance of big moves and thus earn more money if rates goes down a lot.
